# Scala: [InputFormatException: null]

Tags: java, scala

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm using Scala along with the [Jave library](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php).
What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my code:

```
def main {
    val source:File = new File("/Users/music/Desktop/leftright.wav")
      val target:File = new File("leftright.mp3")
      val audio:AudioAttributes = new AudioAttributes()
      audio.setCodec("libmp3lame")
      audio.setBitRate(new java.lang.Integer(128000))
      audio.setChannels(new java.lang.Integer(2))
      audio.setSamplingRate(new java.lang.Integer(44100))
      val attrs:EncodingAttributes = new EncodingAttributes()
      attrs.setFormat("mp3")
      attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio)
      val encoder:Encoder = new Encoder()
      encoder.encode(source, target, attrs)
}

def index = Action {
    main // placed it here just to test
    Ok(views.html.index("play")))
}
```

I'm just following along with the examples [here](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php#10)

---

Full stack trace from console:

```
[error] application - 

! @6hadcflf9 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[InputFormatException: null]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:165) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:162) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
Caused by: it.sauronsoftware.jave.InputFormatException: null
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.parseMultimediaInfo(Encoder.java:659) ~[jave-1.0.2.jar:na]
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:840) ~[jave-1.0.2.jar:na]
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:713) ~[jave-1.0.2.jar:na]
    at controllers.Application$.main(Application.scala:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$index$1.apply(Application.scala:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$index$1.apply(Application.scala:44) ~[classes/:na]
```

Play display:

```
[InputFormatException: null]
In /Users/music/paydemo/app/controllers/Application.scala at line 42.
39      attrs.setFormat("mp3")
40      attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio)
41      val encoder:Encoder = new Encoder()
42      encoder.encode(source, target, attrs)
43  }
```

Comment: @britva You are wrong. You can't _reassign_ a `val`, but you can call any methods of its type.

Comment: This is very unlikely to be related to Scala; it's a problem with the library. You also should provide the stack trace.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I edited in the full stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InputFormatException` is thrown (according to the source of Jave)

> If the source multimedia file cannot be decoded.

Check that the settings you are correct to decode the file. What these settings are depends on your file.